# How to make Swagger API calls use HTTP over HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, ruby-grape

I'm using `grape-swagger` and `grape-swagger-rails` to document my API and it works fine, but when I click in **Try it out!** swagger uses HTTPS protocol which I didn't have it configured yet, how do I switch to HTTP?

Comment: Just a wild guess. The protocol is specified by `schemes` in the spec: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#swagger-object. Maybe there's something similar in `grape-swagger` or `grape-swagger-rails`.

Comment: yeah.. maybe.. but I couldn't find where to set this parameter in these gems.. that's why I started the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the schemes field as bellow (worked for me):

```
add_swagger_documentation(
  api_version: "v1",
  hide_documentation_path: true,
  mount_path: "/api/v1/swagger_doc",
  schemes: 'http',
  hide_format: true
)
```